After using AvalonDock to restore the layout, my original layout name disappeared, and now I don't know how to accurately locate and associate it
After using Avalon Dock to restore the layout, my original layout name disappeared, and now I don't know how to accurately locate and associate it.
dock view
load layout
dock manager
I want to associate the main module with the name with the new layout after restoring the layout, and of course there are possible modules in the new layout, so I can associate the existing ones so that I can easily manage and add new content, but I can't locate it.

Please do not post images of code/errors but provide it as (properly formatted) text
